# Receiving SSL Handshake success/failure events on Tomcat 8 using APR/native connector

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat8, handshake, apr

My tomcat instance is using APR/native connector, which uses OpenSSL under the hood to make SSL connections. I want to receive SSL handshake events, so that any handshake be it success or failure can be logged. I don't see any APR connector option for it.

I am aware of the `-Djavax.net.debug=XXX` option, but that won't work since the connection is going through OpenSSL stack.

- Is there something like **SSLHandshakeCompletion/SSLHandshakeFailure event** that can be captured?
- If not, is there a way to **enable SSL level logging when using APR connector**?

I believe it's a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution for it yet.

Comment: Not possible. If you switch to Java SSL implementation, the debug would anyway log all the traffic by default (XXX=all), which is probably too much. And changing the value of XXX to anything else than "all" is not working well (a bug is referenced).

Comment: @EugèneAdell Thanks for the response. We ended up patching the _libtcnative_ library to explicitly log handshake failure events, since there is no control up the stack to achieve this.